# How to find minimum value of repeated subfield with aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Suppose I have a collection with a large amount of documents that resemble this:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('5b8e52e340a6648cb2cfd93b'),
 u'acetylation': [],
 u'domains': [{u'e-val': 3.7e-31,
               u'end': 764,
               u'pfam_acc': u'PF02190.13',
               u'pfam_name': u'LON_substr_bdg',
               u'start': 568},
              {u'e-val': 0.00048,
               u'end': 311,
               u'pfam_acc': u'PF07719.14',
               u'pfam_name': u'TPR_2',
               u'start': 279},
              {u'e-val': 0.0012,
               u'end': 90,
               u'pfam_acc': u'PF13428.3',
               u'pfam_name': u'TPR_14',
               u'start': 48},
              {u'e-val': 1.9e-10,
               u'end': 516,
               u'pfam_acc': u'PF13923.3',
               u'pfam_name': u'zf-C3HC4_2',
               u'start': 478},
              {u'e-val': 1.4e-06,
               u'end': 281,
               u'pfam_acc': u'PF14559.3',
               u'pfam_name': u'TPR_19',
               u'start': 221},
              {u'e-val': 5.1e-08,
               u'end': 149,
               u'pfam_acc': u'PF15227.3',
               u'pfam_name': u'zf-C3HC4_4',
               u'start': 123}]
}
```

I want to write an aggregation framework that will return the *entire* document that contains the minimum `e-val`. Also, some of the documents do not have any data in this `domain` field (i.e. `u'domains': []`). So far I've tried:

```
#~import stuff above #
...
pipeline = [
     {
     "$unwind": "$domain"

     #~ },
     #~ {
     #~ "$project": { "_id": {}, "minimum_E_val": { "$min": "$domain.e-val" } }
     }
   ]

pprint.pprint(list(prot_data_collection.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

to unwind `domains`, but this results in an empty list. My thinking is to first unwind `domains` (not sure if actually needed), then `$project` so I can use `$min` and keep the document intact (unlike `$group`), and then finally return the document. Not exactly sure where the check for empty list would come in either. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Veeram, this solution gets me what I need.

```
pipeline = [
    {"$unwind": "$domains"},
    {"$match": {"$and":[{"domains":{"$ne":[]}} , { "domains.e-val":{"$gt":0}}]}},
    {"$sort":{"domains.e-val":1}},
    {"$limit":1}
    ]


pprint.pprint(list(protein_data.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

1) unwind to get each array element of $domains in its own record

2) match for domain.e-val's that are not empty (`[]`) and greater than 0

3) sort by domain.e-val in ascending order

4) limit the output to the first document